# Can't use self in static method in php

Tags: php, oop

I can't use `self` in a static method , it gives me this error message : 
`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\dw-usercp\usercp.php on line 136`

here is the source code :

```
class dw_usercp
{
    public static function plugin_activated() {
        self::create_plugin_pages();
    }

    public function create_plugin_pages() {
        $pages = array(
            'signin' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Sign In', 'dw-usercp' ),
                'content' => '[dwusercp-sigin-form]',
                'option_id' => 'login_page'
            ),
            'user-account' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Your Account', 'dw-usercp' ),
                'content' => '[dwusercp-info]',
                'option_id' => 'user_account_page'
            ),
            'edit-user-info' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Edit User Info', 'dw-usercp' ),
                'content' => '[dwusercp-edit-info]',
                'option_id' => 'user_editinfo_page'
            ),
            'profile' => array(
                'title' => __( 'User profile', 'dw-usercp' ),
                'content' => '[dwusercp-profile]',
                'option_id' => 'profile_page'
            ),
            'signup' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Sign Up', 'dw-usercp' ),
                'content' => '[dwusercp-signup-form]',
                'option_id' => 'register_page'
            ),
            'user-lost-password' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Forgot Your Password?', 'dw-usercp' ),
                'content' => '[dwusercp-password-lost-form]',
                'option_id' => 'lost_password_page'
            ),
            'user-password-reset' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Pick a New Password', 'dw-usercp' ),
                'content' => '[dwusercp-password-reset-form]',
                'option_id' => 'password_reset_page'
            )
        );

        foreach( $pages as $slug => $page ) {
            $query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=' . $slug );
            if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
                // Add the page using the data from the array above
                $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                    array(
                        'post_content'   => $page['content'],
                        'post_name'      => $slug,
                        'post_title'     => $page['title'],
                        'post_status'    => 'publish',
                        'post_type'      => 'page',
                        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
                        'comment_status' => 'closed',
                    )
                );

                $this->update_plugin_option( $page['option_id'], $post_id ); // this is the line 136 that the error message says
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update plugin option
     * 
     * @param string $field option id
     * @param mixed $value option new value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update_plugin_option( $field, $value ) {
        $options = get_option("dw_usercp_options");
        $options[$field] = $value;

        update_option( "dw_usercp_options", $options );
    }
}
$dw_usercp = new dw_usercp();

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'dw_usercp', 'plugin_activated' ) );
```

how do i call the `create_plugin_pages()` correctly then?

the `plugin_activated()` has to be static as Wordpress says

Comment: I can't help but laugh (I know it's not constructive). You are using `$this`. The error tells you you **can't use $this in static context**. Let's see - what could the next step possibly be? Can't use `$this`, but you are using `$this`, yet you give yourself the answer in the title :) this is a whole another level of having issues and looking for help, I haven't seen many of these.

Comment: well the problem is caused when you use `self` , how else you wanna call a property or a method of the current class inside a static method? , So the title is correct the error message has nothing to do with the purpose of this question , the question is how can we call a non-static function in a static function when we can't use `self` on it  , thanks to @Ray , i got my answer

Comment: Oh well, I don't want to beat a dead horse but it's really funny how you almost had the answer. Sometimes reading the error message 50 times does help to conclude stuff on your own (which beats someone telling you the answer a trillion times over). Anyway, good luck with your further programming challenges :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a static function, you're not in an instance of the class.  You could:

- instantiate an instance of the class and call the function
- Pass an instatiated object into the static funtion
- Make the `create_plugin_pages`function static and call it with static.
- Convert `plugin_activated` to not be static (MY VOTE)

The static option won't work though since you call `$this` inside `create_plugin_pages`.  So you'll need to go the instatiation route.

Non-static

```
  public function plugin_activated() {
       $this->create_plugin_pages();
   }
```

Here's the passing in an object version

```
   public static function plugin_activated(dw_usercp $a_dw_usercp) {
       $a_dw_usercp->create_plugin_pages();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are using "$this" variable when you're in static context (did you read the error message?)

When in static context, use for methods:

`self::method(args)`;

or

`self::$attr` for variables (attributes)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->update_plugin_option( $page['option_id'], $post_id );
```

is not **`self`**, as referenced in your title. You should be using:

```
self::update_plugin_option( $page['option_id'], $post_id );
```